# Is it possible to generate key for each element when i import JSon from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I imported a json from firebase.
after my first push, i have a key!
Is it possible to generate keys when i am importing   my json?
 [image: datas after push]

Comment: By _importing a json from firebase_ do you mean that you used the user interface button on the top right of the database page to import the json? What do you mean by _importing my json_?

Comment: i have a file.json and and i imported the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the imported data is going to appear exactly as seen in the JSON.  If you want something different, you will have to write code to make it appear differently.

Comment: for my first request to get value ref("../data")  i get an array [] , and after my first push the type change to {}.Do you know why the type change please!

Comment: Yup, you have an array there with integer indexes, then you changed it to an object by adding something else that wasn't an integer.  You should instead parse the JSON an add everything with code - avoid the import entirely.

Comment: yes thanks, so now i test the type like is `if(Array.isArray(data.val())){
          this.setState({electricite:data.val()});
         this.setState({key_elec:data.key})
        } else{
          let tab=[]
          var objetData = data.val();
        
        for (var key in objetData) {
          tab.push(objetData[key])      
            
        }
          this.setState({electricite:tab})
        //        console.log("tabbbbbbbbb",tab)

        }
`